# How can I check if a checkbox is checked in Selenium Python WebDriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've been searching a week how check if a checkbox is checked in Selenium WebDriver with Python, but I find only algorithms from JAVA. I've read the WebDriver docs and it doesn't have an answer for that.
Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found another way that works, but using javascript inside.

```
def is_checked(self, driver, item_id):
  checked = driver.execute_script(
    f"return document.getElementById('{item_id}').checked"
  )
  return checked
```

Answer (score 101):

There is a WebElement property called `is_selected()`, and for a check box this indicates whether or not it is checked. Therefore you can verify if it is checked/unchecked by doing something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('<check_box_name>').is_selected()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id('<check_box_id>').is_selected()
```

I remember having the same issue not being able to find documentation. It's easier to find once you know the name ([here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html?highlight=is_selected#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected) are some docs, `is_selected` is towards the bottom), but the way I have gone about trying to find different options/properties for Selenium objects is to just drop `dir(some_object)` in the code and see what options come up (this is how `is_selected` appeared).

Comment: Thanks for this. If you find that a checkbox is "checked" and you want to change it to "unchecked", how would this be done?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using `driver.find_element_by_name("< check_box_name >").is_selected()`

Comment: How does this differ from the first alternative in [RocketDonkey's 2013/01 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442938)?

Answer (score 2):

```
agreed = driver.find_element_by_id("checkBoxAgreed")
if agreed.get_attribute("checked") != "true":
    agreed.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.id("checkboxId"))
```

(or)

```
checkbox = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(checkboxSelector)
```

, then

```
if checkbox.isSelected():
    print 'Checkbox is selected'
```

Comment: The first alternative looks entirely similar to one in [RocketDonkey's 2013 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442938).

Comment: Replace `isSelected` with `is_selected` because in the selenium python api the function name is snake cased. I would make the edit but the SO rules prohibit edits that are less than 6 characters.

Answer (score -3):

```
def assert_checkbox_status (id, expect):
    global browser
    field = browser.find_element_by_id(id)
    assert field.get_attribute ('checked')== expect
```

Example of use:

```
assert_checkbox('activate', True) ==> assert if checkbox is checked
assert_checkbox('activate', None) ==> assert if checkbox is unchecked
```