# How to verify disabled textbox in selenium python (Pytest)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

The below html code is textbox which has disabled.

How to assert in selenium python whether the textbox is disabled or enabled

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a checkbox is checked in Selenium Python Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442636/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-selenium-python-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

As said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442636/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-selenium-python-webdriver) you can use `is_selected()` function after selecting the element in selenium.

This function returns `True` if it is selected.

Comment: getting assertion error for is_selected() for the below code

ownerSelect = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//label[starts-with(@for,'Ownerbtn')]/span[3])[1]")))
        assert ownerSelect.is_selected(),"Owner box not checked"
        log.info("Owner box checked")

Comment: Try this way: ```ownerSelect = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"(//label[starts-with(@for,'Ownerbtn')]/span[3])[1]"))).is_selected()```