# How to count the number of selected checkboxes in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selecting checkboxes(2) randomly using selenium Python. After selection is done, I want to verify the number of checked checkboxes. How to do that?

Below is my code:

```py
checkboxes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@type='checkbox']")
print(len(checkboxes))
for x in range(2):
    opt = random.choice(checkboxes)
    if opt.is_enabled():
        opt.click()
```

Comment: In selenium there is an `is_selected()` method which can used to check if a checkbox is selected or not. You can refer to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442636/how-can-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-selenium-python-webdriver

Comment: Update the question with the HTML of the checkbox when 1) Not selected & 2) Selected